# React Debounce with useState

Tags: reactjs

I have this implementation of debounce that works perfectly.

```
import React from "react";

const TIME_MS = 2000;

const useDebounce = () => {
  const [, setTimerId] = React.useState<NodeJS.Timeout>();

  return React.useCallback((func: () => void) => {
    const newTimerId = setTimeout(func, TIME_MS);
    setTimerId(oldTimerId => {
      clearTimeout(oldTimerId);
      return newTimerId;
    });
  }, []);
};
```

But if I move the line `const newTimerId = setTimeout(func, TIME_MS);` into the `setTimeout` than it doesn't work properly anymore and I don't know why. I feel like I am missing some major concept on how React works. Can someone explain it to me?

Code with the modification:

```
import React from "react";

const TIME_MS = 2000;

const useDebounce = () => {
  const [, setTimerId] = React.useState<NodeJS.Timeout>();

  return React.useCallback((func: () => void) => {
    setTimerId(oldTimerId => {
      const newTimerId = setTimeout(func, TIME_MS);
      clearTimeout(oldTimerId);
      return newTimerId;
    });
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: better look for existing implementation as they will be more robust. As to your code, the updater function passed to setState must be pure (no side effects). For example in strict mode they can be invoked twice.

Comment: I've seen robust implementations. But I am intellectually interested in learning why this implementation is flawed. By flawed I mean it will execute `func` every time the returned function is called, which means the previous `setTimeout` is no being properly cleared.

Comment: I told you one thing which you shouldn't be doing, you are calling timeout inside updater function, i.e. making side effect. the updater function should be *pure*